# How to bundle script into dmg file

Tags: python, c++, qt

I am creating a dmg for qt standalone application using macdeployqt. I am calling a python script from qt application. I am not clear how can i bundle python script with dmg file.

thanks

Comment: Indeed, you are not clear...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get that done using QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA

https://forum.qt.io/topic/67661/bundle-python-into-qt-application-dmg-and-exe/7